# awk command: adding prefix to an csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am trying to add an prefix to my csv file. Below is the source csv

```
  A,B
121ABC,London
2212ABC,Paris
312ABC,Tokyo
```

I am using the following  `awk` command

```
$ awk -F=',' -vOFS=',' '{$2="AC_"$2; print}' t.csv >t1.csv
```

But, the output is somewhat adding another column to the csv file.

```
A,B,AC_
121ABC,London,AC_
2212ABC,Paris,AC_
312ABC,Tokyo,AC_
```

Any pointers as to where the error is?

Comment: 2 identical answers posted at one time (with 18 seconds difference). That's curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting FS to `=,` instead of `,`. Use `-F','` or `-v FS=','` but not `-F=','`.

Since you require `,` for both input and output field separators you should be setting them together to that value in one place rather than setting them both separately to the same value:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2="AC_"$2; print}' t.csv >t1.csv
```

Comment: I changed it to ` awk -F',' -OFS',' '{$2="AC_"$2; print}' t.csv >t1.csv` The output seems to add suffix to each element in the second column e.g. `121ABC,London AC_
2212ABC,Paris AC_
312ABC,Tokyo AC_`

Comment: I can't imagine what awk might be interpreting `-OFS','` as but it's not what you're hoping for as there is no `-OFS` argument. Just do what I showed and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2 = "AC_" $2} 1' file

A,AC_B
121ABC,AC_London
2212ABC,AC_Paris
312ABC,AC_Tokyo
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps simpler with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/,/&AC_/' file

  A,AC_B
121ABC,AC_London
2212ABC,AC_Paris
312ABC,AC_Tokyo
```